# How to obtain number of pages in a Crystal Reports .NET report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have a web application in which I render one or more Crystal Reports and then merge them into one PDF. What I'd like to do is obtain the number of pages from one CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument object then then set that value as a parameter in the subsequent ReportDocuments in order to continue the page numbering correctly. Does the ReportDocument class expose a way of obtaining the number of pages? If not, are there other ways?

I am NOT using a Crystal Report Viewer.

I am using CrystalReports for Visual Studio 2010 and C# .NET 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to use the code below:

```
reportDocument.FormatEngine.GetLastPageNumber(new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportPageRequestContext());
```

Intellisense will not pick up the "FormatEngine" property of the ReportDocument, so you need to type it manually, then Intellisense will show "GetLastPageNumber" method and you can go from there.

I had seen this solution before but the lack of Intellisense support caused me to think that perhaps I had the wrong version of the Crystal Report object to leverage the "FormatEngine" property.

Comment: but this Method is Very Slow if the Pages are more than 200, 1000 ... very very slow.. takes around minutes to complete .. why its happening?

Comment: @Gokul, does your report have many subreports embedded in it? Also, have a look [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2046747). The Crystal Report expert states that this method "may slow down the time it takes for the report to come up as the whole report will need to be processed, formatted, etc."

Comment: yea only one.. based on grouping and selecting sub records.. Is that the Actual reason for being Slow? oh.. but i have asked one more question regarding this..! the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18407821/2477167)

Comment: @Gokul, from reading your other post the answer is yes, the slowness is most likely caused by the subreport, which if in your Detail sections will read from the database each time the section is rendered, which would be thousands of times.

Comment: Loving It you save my day Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**TotalPageCount** properties of the CrystalDecisions will resolve that issue.