# How to Apply Multicolumn in another Details Section C#, Crystal Reports, vs2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, subreport

I am Having a Report

[image: My Report Design]

In here am Having 4 Details Section `a,b,c,d` , and I want to apply Multi column in only one Details section, that is the Section which has the Sub Report Currently. I Have used Sub report because I thought, applying multiple column to only one Details Section is not Possible....

and Got into another Burden, My Report can have more than 2500 pages, while using subreports, it is very slow while printing and / or navigating to last Page.

So, only in the `Section C` I have to show data in two Columns Across Data Layout. And the Rest of the Sections `a, b, d`, can have only one column.

And also, I have 2 Tables `rptDoc` -> Documents[List of All Documents] and `rptSche` -> Schedules[List of All Schedules]. every Document can have 1 or more schedules each, So, I have to show Document Record as well as Associated Schedules.. the Schedules must be in `Section C` with 2 Columns.

Is that Possible??

Answer (score 0):

To your first question regarding the columns: If the other Detail sections (a, b, c & d) of the report are pulling from the same data source then there is no reason why you can't place columns wherever you want in those sections. Simply place the fields as required in each section.
You can also suppress/hide the sections/fields as necessary. I don't know the specifics of your requirements so I can't elaborate but Crystal Reports should give you the flexibility you need.

As for your second question, it sounds as though you can link the `rptDoc` table with the `rptSche` table however necessary and as I mentioned for your first question place the fields in whatever sections you need.

The need for subreports arises when you need to place data in the report that can't be linked with the report's data source or where you need specific data to appear in a certain place or time out of the flow of the main report. You always want to avoid using subreports as much as possible because database reads are made everytime the report encounters the subreport, and if that happens to be in the Details section then there can be thousands of repetitive reads.